# シェルスクリプトでリストから近い時間のものを抽出したい。

Tags: linux, bash

このようなリストがあります。このリストは標準入力から入力されます。

```
-06
26
56
-07
26
54
-08
27
55
-10
01
-11
01
-12
01
-13
01
52
-14
52
```

次にdateコマンドで時刻を取得し変数に格納します。

そして最初にリストにある時間で最も近い時間を捜索します。
次にそこから３つの時刻を取得して返すようにしたいです。

たとえば８時30分であれば配列で「0855 1001 1101」を返します。
また16時であればそれ以上直近のものがないのでその場合は最初に戻り翌日の6時のものから捜索し数字冒頭に99を付加した「990626 990656 990726」を返したいです。これは他にもデーターを処理して近い順にソートする際に当日のものが別のデーターに含まれていた場合に翌日のものが当日のものより早くなってしまうことを防ぐためにつけるものです。

お手数おかけしますがよろしくおねがいします

Comment: 入力データの書式/ルールを質問文に追記したほうがよいと思います。(先頭が「`-`」で始まっている行が「時」を表しており、それ以降の数字で始まる行はその「時」の「分」を示している、と予想しますが、あっているか判断できませんので) また、ロジックについても条件を詳細化して記述したほうがよいと思います。(「近い」とは、指定時刻より先の時刻である、入力データの末尾まで検索した際は先頭に戻って検索する、等)

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず sed と awk と/bin/sh で書いてみました。
ただしある程度複雑なテキスト処理になったらシェルスクリプトではなくもう少し高機能なスクリプト言語(perl, python, ruby など)で書いた方が性能も保守性もよくなるかと思います。

```
#! /bin/sh

# 1. create today table
TMP_FILE=`mktemp`
awk -F'-' 'BEGIN{OFS=""} {if ($2 != "" ) hour=$2; else print hour, $1}' - > ${TMP_FILE}

# 2. create today and tommorow table
TMP_FILE2=`mktemp`
cat ${TMP_FILE} >> ${TMP_FILE2}
sed -e s/^/99/g ${TMP_FILE} >> ${TMP_FILE2}

# 3. get current time
NOW=`date +%H%M`
#NOW=0830 # for test
#NOW=1600 # for test

# 4. search 3 items after NOW
awk "{ if (\$0 >= \"$NOW\") print \$0 }" < ${TMP_FILE2} | head -3

# 5. clean up tmp files
if [ -f ${TMP_FILE2} ]; then
    rm ${TMP_FILE2}
fi

if [ -f ${TMP_FILE} ]; then
    rm ${TMP_FILE}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK でよろしければこんな感じでしょうか。

```
cat list.txt | awk '
{
    # read input file and generate list of time
    if (gsub("^-", "")) {
        hh = $0
    } else {
        list[++i] = hh $0;
    }
}
END {
    # get current time
    "date +%H%M" | getline
    date = $0

    # add tomorrow's list
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        list[j + i] = "99" list[j]
    }

    # search in the list
    for (j = 1; j <= 2 * i; j++) {
        if (date <= list[j]) {
            # found and print 3 items
            for (k = j;  k < j + 3; k++) {
                print list[k]
            }
            exit
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

sed でも一行で書けます。

時分の文字列比較が多少厄介ですが、「以上」を求めるには「未満」を全て削除すればよいと発想転換できれば難しくありません。
例えば、`830` 以上を求めるには `[^8-9]..` と `8[^3-9].` と `83[^0-9]` を削除すれば残った数が答えになります。

```
HHMM=`date +%H%M`; H0=${HHMM:0:1}; H1=${HHMM:1:1}; M0=${HHMM:2:1}; M1=${HHMM:3:1}

sed '-e:a;N;${;:b;s/-\([0-2][0-9]\)\(\n[^-]*\n\)\([0-5][0-9]\n\)/-\1\2\1\3/g;tb;s/-\([0-2][0-9]\)\n\([0-5][0-9]\)/\1\2/g;h;s/\(^\|\n\)/\199/g;x;s/$/\n/;s/[^'$H0'-9]...\n//g;s/'$H0'[^'$H1'-9]..\n//g;s/'$H0$H1'[^'$M0'-9].\n//g;s/'$H0$H1$M0'[^'$M1'-9]\n//g;s/\n$//;G;s/^\n//;s/\n/ /;s/\n/ /;s/\n.*//;};ba'
```